# How to check if a text is all white space characters in client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if a user input text is all white space characters (space, tab, enter etc) in client side?

Comment: If you don't know regex, prepare your head to explode.

Comment: @GabRoyer, not with jQuery, it won't! See MacAnthony's answer below.

Answer (score 98):

This question is tagged with jQuery. In jQuery, you can run the following:

```
if ( $.trim( $('#myInput').val() ) == '' )
    alert('input is blank');
```

Answer (score 42):

`/^\s+$/.test(userText)`

Change the `+` to `*` to include the empty string `''` as a positive match.

**Edit**

More often than not though you need to trim whitespace from user-entered text and simply test if it's non-empty:

```
userText = userText.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
if (userText === '') {
    // text was all whitespace
} else {
    // text has real content, now free of leading/trailing whitespace
}
```

Comment: FWIW /^\s\s*/ is quicker than /^\s+/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the following the same as the double replace? 

x.replace( /^\s*(.*?)\s*$/, '$1' );

Answer (score 32):

This will also work:

```
var text = "   ";
text.trim().length == 0; //true
```

Comment: This does not work in all browsers. See MacAnthony's response.

Comment: Interesting would be to know if this is faster or if the regex solution is faster.

Comment: Not sure which browsers this doesn't work in (I'd be curious) but I just tested in Chrome (62.0.3202.94), Firefox (59.0), and Safari (11.0.1) and it works in those.

Comment: @BradyDowling it does not work in IE < 9, [according to CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=trim).

Answer (score 8):

Like this...

```
function isEmpty(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see if a file contains all white space or is empty, I would recommend testing the inversion and inverting the result. That way you don't need to worry about special cases around empty string.

all whitespace is the same as no non-whitespace so:

```
function isWhitespaceOrEmpty(text) {
   return !/[^\s]/.test(text);
}
```

If you don't want empty strings you can modify it slightly:

```
function isWhitespaceNotEmpty(text) {
   return text.length > 0 && !/[^\s]/.test(text);
}
```

Comment: When I read the regex I read: "Check string starting with whitespace", but how come it works when you type " abc"?

Comment: You are reading the regular expression incorrectly. [^\s] means any character that that is not whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

To find whitespace generated by JavaScript and between elements use:

```
var trimmed = $.trim( $('p').text() );

if ( trimmed === '' ){
    //function...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Josh's answer is very close to this, but according to w3schools (in May 2014) it is as follows:

```
function isEmpty(str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'').length == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
//                      ^ start string 
//                      || \s+ white space one or more times 
//                      || || $ = end string                        
//                      || || ||
//                      \/ \/ \/

const isAllWhiteSpace = /^\s+$/.test(myvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

yo, we can check simply bt trim, as javascript is tagged in question,

```js
console.log('     '.trim() === '')//check for all empty spaces

console.log('     '.trim() === '')//check for all empty tabs

console.log('\n \n'.trim() === '')//check for all empty enter(empty new line)

console.log('         \n'.trim() === '')//check for all spaces, tabs and new line
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that has worked for me:

```
 $("#example_form").validate({
    rules: {
        example_field: {
            required: {
                depends: function () {
                    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        },

    },
    messages: { example_field: {required: "Custom Validation Message for example_field"}, }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <label for="password">Password* <small id="pass-status"></small></label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control my-metro-inputs my-metro-input-border my-metro-input-padding" placeholder="password" value="" required onfocusout="passwordChecker(this)">
        </div>
```

```js
function passwordChecker(e){
    var pass = document.getElementById('password');
    var passStatus = document.getElementById('pass-status');
    var inValid = /\s/;
    if(pass){
        if(pass.value.length == 0 || pass.value.length < 0){
            pass.classList.remove('my-input-success');
            pass.classList.add('my-input-danger');
            if(passStatus){
                passStatus.innerHTML = "<b style='color:red'> field must not empty or less then Zero ( 0 ) !</b>";
                
            }
            return false;
        }else if((inValid.test(pass.value))){
            pass.classList.remove('my-input-success');
            pass.classList.add('my-input-danger');
            if(passStatus){
                passStatus.innerHTML = "<b style='color:red'> no whitespaces allowed !</b>";   
            }
            return false; 
        }else{
            pass.classList.add('my-input-success');
            pass.classList.remove('my-input-danger');
            if(passStatus){
                passStatus.innerHTML = "";
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

```css
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto
}

.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px
    }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .container {
        width: 970px
    }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 1170px
    }
}

.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px
}

.col-xs-1,
.col-sm-1,
.col-md-1,
.col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-sm-2,
.col-md-2,
.col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-sm-3,
.col-md-3,
.col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-md-4,
.col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-sm-6,
.col-md-6,
.col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-sm-7,
.col-md-7,
.col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-sm-8,
.col-md-8,
.col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-sm-9,
.col-md-9,
.col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-sm-10,
.col-md-10,
.col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-sm-11,
.col-md-11,
.col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-md-12,
.col-lg-12 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px
}

.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12 {
    float: left
}

.col-xs-12 {
    width: 100%
}

.col-xs-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%
}

.col-xs-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%
}

.col-xs-9 {
    width: 75%
}

.col-xs-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%
}

.col-xs-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%
}

.col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%
}

.col-xs-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%
}

.col-xs-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%
}

.col-xs-3 {
    width: 25%
}

.col-xs-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%
}

.col-xs-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%
}

.col-xs-pull-12 {
    right: 100%
}

.col-xs-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%
}

.col-xs-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%
}

.col-xs-pull-9 {
    right: 75%
}

.col-xs-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%
}

.col-xs-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%
}

.col-xs-pull-6 {
    right: 50%
}

.col-xs-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%
}

.col-xs-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%
}

.col-xs-pull-3 {
    right: 25%
}

.col-xs-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%
}

.col-xs-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%
}

.col-xs-pull-0 {
    right: auto
}

.col-xs-push-12 {
    left: 100%
}

.col-xs-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%
}

.col-xs-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%
}

.col-xs-push-9 {
    left: 75%
}

.col-xs-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%
}

.col-xs-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%
}

.col-xs-push-6 {
    left: 50%
}

.col-xs-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%
}

.col-xs-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%
}

.col-xs-push-3 {
    left: 25%
}

.col-xs-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%
}

.col-xs-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%
}

.col-xs-push-0 {
    left: auto
}

.col-xs-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%
}

.col-xs-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%
}

.col-xs-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%
}

.col-xs-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%
}

.col-xs-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%
}

.col-xs-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%
}

.col-xs-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%
}

.col-xs-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%
}

.col-xs-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%
}

.col-xs-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%
}

.col-xs-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%
}

.col-xs-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%
}

.col-xs-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0
}

@media (min-width:768px) {

    .col-sm-1,
    .col-sm-2,
    .col-sm-3,
    .col-sm-4,
    .col-sm-5,
    .col-sm-6,
    .col-sm-7,
    .col-sm-8,
    .col-sm-9,
    .col-sm-10,
    .col-sm-11,
    .col-sm-12 {
        float: left
    }

    .col-sm-12 {
        width: 100%
    }

    .col-sm-11 {
        width: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-10 {
        width: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-9 {
        width: 75%
    }

    .col-sm-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-7 {
        width: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-6 {
        width: 50%
    }

    .col-sm-5 {
        width: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-3 {
        width: 25%
    }

    .col-sm-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-1 {
        width: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-12 {
        right: 100%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-11 {
        right: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-10 {
        right: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-9 {
        right: 75%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-8 {
        right: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-7 {
        right: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-6 {
        right: 50%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-5 {
        right: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-4 {
        right: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-3 {
        right: 25%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-2 {
        right: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-1 {
        right: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-pull-0 {
        right: auto
    }

    .col-sm-push-12 {
        left: 100%
    }

    .col-sm-push-11 {
        left: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-push-10 {
        left: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-push-9 {
        left: 75%
    }

    .col-sm-push-8 {
        left: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-push-7 {
        left: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-push-6 {
        left: 50%
    }

    .col-sm-push-5 {
        left: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-push-4 {
        left: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-push-3 {
        left: 25%
    }

    .col-sm-push-2 {
        left: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-push-1 {
        left: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-push-0 {
        left: auto
    }

    .col-sm-offset-12 {
        margin-left: 100%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-9 {
        margin-left: 75%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-7 {
        margin-left: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-6 {
        margin-left: 50%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-3 {
        margin-left: 25%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-1 {
        margin-left: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-sm-offset-0 {
        margin-left: 0
    }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {

    .col-md-1,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-md-9,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-md-12 {
        float: left
    }

    .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%
    }

    .col-md-11 {
        width: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-10 {
        width: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-9 {
        width: 75%
    }

    .col-md-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%
    }

    .col-md-5 {
        width: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%
    }

    .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-1 {
        width: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-pull-12 {
        right: 100%
    }

    .col-md-pull-11 {
        right: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-pull-10 {
        right: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-pull-9 {
        right: 75%
    }

    .col-md-pull-8 {
        right: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-pull-7 {
        right: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-pull-6 {
        right: 50%
    }

    .col-md-pull-5 {
        right: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-pull-4 {
        right: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-pull-3 {
        right: 25%
    }

    .col-md-pull-2 {
        right: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-pull-1 {
        right: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-pull-0 {
        right: auto
    }

    .col-md-push-12 {
        left: 100%
    }

    .col-md-push-11 {
        left: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-push-10 {
        left: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-push-9 {
        left: 75%
    }

    .col-md-push-8 {
        left: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-push-7 {
        left: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-push-6 {
        left: 50%
    }

    .col-md-push-5 {
        left: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-push-4 {
        left: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-push-3 {
        left: 25%
    }

    .col-md-push-2 {
        left: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-push-1 {
        left: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-push-0 {
        left: auto
    }

    .col-md-offset-12 {
        margin-left: 100%
    }

    .col-md-offset-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-offset-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-offset-9 {
        margin-left: 75%
    }

    .col-md-offset-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-offset-7 {
        margin-left: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-offset-6 {
        margin-left: 50%
    }

    .col-md-offset-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-offset-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-offset-3 {
        margin-left: 25%
    }

    .col-md-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-md-offset-1 {
        margin-left: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-md-offset-0 {
        margin-left: 0
    }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {

    .col-lg-1,
    .col-lg-2,
    .col-lg-3,
    .col-lg-4,
    .col-lg-5,
    .col-lg-6,
    .col-lg-7,
    .col-lg-8,
    .col-lg-9,
    .col-lg-10,
    .col-lg-11,
    .col-lg-12 {
        float: left
    }

    .col-lg-12 {
        width: 100%
    }

    .col-lg-11 {
        width: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-10 {
        width: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-9 {
        width: 75%
    }

    .col-lg-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-7 {
        width: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-6 {
        width: 50%
    }

    .col-lg-5 {
        width: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-3 {
        width: 25%
    }

    .col-lg-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-1 {
        width: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-12 {
        right: 100%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-11 {
        right: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-10 {
        right: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-9 {
        right: 75%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-8 {
        right: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-7 {
        right: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-6 {
        right: 50%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-5 {
        right: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-4 {
        right: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-3 {
        right: 25%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-2 {
        right: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-1 {
        right: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-pull-0 {
        right: auto
    }

    .col-lg-push-12 {
        left: 100%
    }

    .col-lg-push-11 {
        left: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-push-10 {
        left: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-push-9 {
        left: 75%
    }

    .col-lg-push-8 {
        left: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-push-7 {
        left: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-push-6 {
        left: 50%
    }

    .col-lg-push-5 {
        left: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-push-4 {
        left: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-push-3 {
        left: 25%
    }

    .col-lg-push-2 {
        left: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-push-1 {
        left: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-push-0 {
        left: auto
    }

    .col-lg-offset-12 {
        margin-left: 100%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-9 {
        margin-left: 75%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-7 {
        margin-left: 58.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-6 {
        margin-left: 50%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-3 {
        margin-left: 25%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66666667%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-1 {
        margin-left: 8.33333333%
    }

    .col-lg-offset-0 {
        margin-left: 0
    }
}









.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.dl-horizontal dd:before,
.dl-horizontal dd:after,
.container:before,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:before,
.row:after,
.form-horizontal .form-group:before,
.form-horizontal .form-group:after,
.btn-toolbar:before,
.btn-toolbar:after,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:before,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after,
.nav:before,
.nav:after,
.navbar:before,
.navbar:after,
.navbar-header:before,
.navbar-header:after,
.navbar-collapse:before,
.navbar-collapse:after,
.pager:before,
.pager:after,
.panel-body:before,
.panel-body:after,
.modal-footer:before,
.modal-footer:after {
    display: table;
    content: " "
}

.clearfix:after,
.dl-horizontal dd:after,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:after,
.form-horizontal .form-group:after,
.btn-toolbar:after,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after,
.nav:after,
.navbar:after,
.navbar-header:after,
.navbar-collapse:after,
.pager:after,
.panel-body:after,
.modal-footer:after {
    clear: both
}

.center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto
}

.pull-right {
    float: right !important
}

/* forms */
.form-row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-row > .col,
.form-row > [class*=col-] {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.col {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.col {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.margin-top-25px {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

button,
input {
    overflow: visible;
}

.form-check-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-check-inline {
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: .75rem;
}
.form-check-inline {
    position: relative;
    top: 33px;
    width: 10%;
}
.form-check {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 1.25rem;
}

.form-check-inline .form-check-input {
    position: static;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: .3125rem;
    margin-left: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox],
input[type=radio] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

.form-check-input {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: .3rem;
    margin-left: -1.25rem;
}
/* forms */
*{ box-sizing: border-box}
.my-metro-student-registration-form-container {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
/* inputs only */
.my-metro-form .my-metro-inputs{
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.my-metro-form .my-metro-input-padding{
    padding: 18px 15px 18px 15px;
}

.my-metro-form .my-metro-input-border{
    border-color: #eeeeee;
}

.my-metro-form .my-metro-inputs:focus{
    border-color: #84c340;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.my-metro-form .my-metro-input-number{
    max-width: 100%;
}

    /* inputs warnings and border colors */
.my-input-success{
    border: 1px solid #12c512 !important;
}
.my-input-danger{
    border: 1px solid #f52828 !important;
}

/* inputs buttons */
.my-metro-form .my-metro-input-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.my-metro-form .my-metro-btn-success{
    background: #84c340;
    color: white;
}

.my-metro-form .my-metro-btn-padding{
   padding: 18px 15px 18px 15px; 
}

.my-metro-form .my-metro-btn-full-width{
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
}
.my-metro-form .my-metro-input-btn:hover{
    background-color: #6aa32d;
    color: white;
}

/* notice */
.my-metro-notice-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.my-metro-notice {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px 0px 6px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 5px auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: "Muli";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: inherit;
}

.my-metro-notice-warning {
    border-left: 4px solid #fb1922;
    color: black;
    background: whitesmoke;
}

.my-metro-notice-align-left {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
     <label for="password">Password* <small id="pass-status"></small></label>
     <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control my-metro-inputs my-metro-input-border my-metro-input-padding" placeholder="password" value="" required onfocusout="passwordChecker(this)">
</div>
<!-- the only this in question is about whitespace check so -->

<pre>

 var inValid = /\s/;
 var value = " ur value with spaces like this " or " ";

  if((inValid.test(value))){
      console.log("white space");
  }else if((!inValid.test(value))){
      console.log("no space");
  }



/* in this code the invalid variable hold rg = regular expression like 
    / \s /
    
    the \s = whitespace
    and more are discussed in link: 
    http://www.javascripter.net/faq/regularexpressionsyntax.htm */
</pre>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.