# How do I check a DOM value is not empty and then copy it in another place in DOM tree

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="destination">--here needs to copy the value of destination--</div>

<div class="block-inner clearfix">
<div class="contextual-links-wrapper">
<div class="content"> $ 300 </div>
</div>
```

I just want to check if `<div class="content"> ...</div>` is not empty and then copy the value into `<div class="destination"></div>`...How do I achieve that?

I expect is something like

```
if (!jQuery(".content:empty")) {
...logic here...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = jQuery(".content").text();
if (text) { jQuery(".destination").text(text); }
```

Comment: weird..your solution work in console but not inside the code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = $.trim($('.content').text());
if(content) {
    $('.destination').text(content);
}
```

If you want to move DOM nodes, you can use:

```
var $nodes = $('.content').children();
if($nodes.length) {
    $('.destination').empty().append($nodes);
}
```

If you want to copy nodes, use `.append($nodes.clone(true, true))`.

Information about these methods can be found in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Use contents() instead of children()?

Comment: @Jleagle: Yes, if the element contains text nodes and element nodes. Good thinking.

Answer (score 0):

To access the inner HTML of a div use .html().

```
var value = $('.content').html();
```

Then you can check the value using a regex to check for whitespace and if its empty. See the link below.

[How to check if a text is all white space characters in client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172206/how-to-check-if-a-text-is-all-white-space-characters-in-client-side)

Then you can set destination div to the content in value.

```
$('.destination').html(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!($.trim($('.content').val())))
{

$('.destination').val($('.content').val());

}
```

Comment: val() I think is working for forms only..otherwise is undefined.