# Javascript: check if the user's input text is "white-space language"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are human languages in which its words are cut with white space,let say, white-space language:

```
          e.g. English: I[whitespace]love[whitespace]you.
```

And there are human languages in which its characters are not cut with white space, let say, non-white-space language:

```
          e.g. Chinese: 我爱你
```

I wondered how to check if the user's input text is white-space language.

As suggested, to clarify the nature of the problem:

The criteria for checking should not be checking if there's frequent occurrence of whitespace in the text, since such method would mistakingly consider "IloveU" as a non-white-space language.

Comment: Your question is very broad. What have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172206/how-to-check-if-a-text-is-all-white-space-characters-in-client-side

Comment: Is your question simply, "How do I test if an input field contains *any* whitespace characters?" If not, what are the parameters that distinguish a whitespace-using language with a non-whitespace language? We can help you solve programming obstacles, but we cannot necessarily help you decide *what you want your code to do*.

Comment: Four upvotes for this question? Seriously??

Comment: I think this is quite interesting question. Maybe it could be better put but still, how to distinguish between correct sentence in non-white-space language like 我爱你, and filter out garbage in white-space language like "Iloveyou"?

Comment: A character can be used by multiple languages. Some could use spaces and some don't. What you want to obtain doesn't seem properly defined.

Comment: What you call "user's input text"? I can write in english, français, español, Русский, 日本語 in the same sentence, and its hard to detect them

Comment: Thought it was about [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) esolang.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sentence = "This is a test sentence";
var searched = sentence.search(" "); // Returns the first index of the white space

if((searched !=null)&&(searched >0))
{
  alert("It is a white-space language");
}
else
{
   alert("It is not a white-space language")
}
```

> **You can also use:**

```
var matched = sentence.match(" "); // Returns the array of the white space
if((matched !=null)&&(matched.length > 0))
{
   alert("It is a white-space language");
}
else
{
   alert("It is not a white-space language")
}
```

Comment: This is probably correct in most cases, but would fail if only one word was typed in the input box.

Comment: I guess the question was to determine a language based on their "white spaces".

But if you are looking for individual words then you should be going for a dictionary of words.